# How to get permanent Raw Git Hub link in JS File?

Tags: javascript, git, github

New to GitHub; I am currently using a Raw Guthub URL in my Javascript File:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myusername/test/db782ed409a2fecd7af810131b08394795a24222/myfile.svg

I am unsure, however, how to get a permanent link, as this URL constantly changes. Any suggestions as to how I might proceed?

Comment: Is the file part of the same project as the JavaScript file? Or put another way, is there a reason you have to reference the file at the full Github URL?

Comment: Yes, the URL is an SVG Map file that complements the functionality of the JS file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a branch name instead of an object ID in the path:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/checkout.c
```

Note the use of `master` here.

However, while it's fine for you to link and refer to those URLs, it's not a good idea to use those URLs for your app's assets, since they aren't designed for that and GitHub doesn't permit that. You should host the SVG file on your own server or on the same server that the JavaScript file is being hosted on.